# Django manage.py error when run from a shell script

Tags: python, django, sh

When I type and execute the command `python manage.py runserver localhost:8080` directly in the terminal everything works fine but when I place the command inside a shell script I get the following error:[image]

The script contains  the following:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have any spaces or characters in the script after `runserver`?

Comment: That's it! I did wrote the script with vim and I forgot about the space characters. Can you upgrade your comment to an answer?

Comment: Fair enough, I have made an answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spaces in the script after `runserver`.

You should remove these to ensure you're only running the desired command without any indication of host / port.